# My question is why won't my inputted text into an edittext show up in another textview when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

So I've converted inputs from editTexts into integers so I can use them in equations in an if else statement, and then converted the result of the math into a string so I can print the result. I'm trying to make an app to help with physics. I'm a beginner. Tell me if you need more information, like the xml file or the manifest file.

velocity.java

```
    EditText editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            EditText editText3=findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            Button solve=findViewById(R.id.solve);
            final String veloInput=editText1.getText().toString();
            final String disInput = editText2.getText().toString();
            final String timInput = editText3.getText().toString();
            final TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            solve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if (veloInput.equals("v")) {
                        int distInput = Integer.parseInt(disInput);
                        int timeInput = Integer.parseInt(timInput);
                        int value = distInput / timeInput;
                        String strValue = Integer.toString(value);
                        textView.setText(strValue);
                    }
```

I want it to type the string strValue into the textView, but nothing happens when I press the button "solve".

Comment: Have you walked through it in a debugger?  Is veloInput =="v"?  Is the click handler firing at all?

Comment: Don't use `==` for String comparison in Java. Use `.equals()`.

Comment: It looks like you're getting the text before you're even setting the on click listener. This means that if you change the text, your on click listener won't get the new value. Try moving your `getText()` calls inside your onClick function.

Comment: The console doesn't say any errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `editText1.getText().toString()` you will get the string from editText1 **at that time**. If the user changes the value of the textbox, none of your variables will reflect that change. Try moving your getText calls inside the onClick function:

```
EditText editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText editText3=findViewById(R.id.editText3);
Button solve=findViewById(R.id.solve);
final TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView5);
solve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        final String veloInput = editText1.getText().toString();
        final String disInput = editText2.getText().toString();
        final String timInput = editText3.getText().toString();
        if (veloInput.equals("v")) {
            int distInput = Integer.parseInt(disInput);
            int timeInput = Integer.parseInt(timInput);
            int value = distInput / timeInput;
            String strValue = Integer.toString(value);
            textView.setText(strValue);
        }
    }
});
```